# What value will be returned when a Table got updated?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.2

I am using cakePHP 1.26.
I was trying to update a Table using these lines of code:

```
$c = "helloworld";
$q="UPDATE user SET avatar='{$c}' WHERE user_id='999999'";
$result=$this->Test->User->query($q);

if($result==true){echo "success";}
else{echo "failed";}
```

I noticed that the Table was updated successfully, but I still saw the "failed" message.
It seems that the value of $result is neither True nor False.

I have no idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`query()` returns the result set from the SQL query. You won't get a success vs. failure result. That said, you probably shouldn't be using `query()` anyway. There's a function for this; it's called `saveField()` and it returns false on failure.

```
$this->Test->User->id = 999999;
$result = $this->Test->User->saveField('avatar', $c);
if ($result !== false) echo "success";
else echo "failed";
```

If you insist on using `query()` there's no reason to go to another model. It just executes an SQL query. This would work as well as what you wrote:

```
$this->query($q);
```

Incidentally, `if ($result == true)` is redundant and generally considered poor form. just `if ($result)` will work identically.

Comment: You probably mean `$this->Test->User->saveField()`... Regardless, solid answer. There's no reason not to use Cake's ORM here.

Comment: D'oh! You're right, I meant `$this->Test->User->saveField`. Editing now.

Answer (score 1):

An update query on SQL returns **number of rows updated**. So it might be returning an integer not bool.

Answer (score 1):

after the table is updates it returns the affected rows numbers.
so after your query finished if you would call this function "mysql_affected_rows" you would get the affected rows,and if it is greater than 0 that means the query excecuted succesfully and if it is 0 then the update is not done ..

Comment: oops ! you are using cakephp .here is the query how it should be done 

$c = "helloworld";
$q="UPDATE user SET avatar='{$c}' WHERE user_id='999999'";
if($this->Test->User->query($q))
echo "success";
}
else{echo "failed";

}

################################
for note it returns you the id of the row which is being updated 
you can get it by
$this->Test->User->id

Comment: and for your information,i am assuming that user_id is the primary key in your table user,but as you are using cakephp 
you should name all primary keys as id

then you can write that query like this 
$this->Test->User->id=99999;
$this->Test->User->set('avatar', 'helloworld');
if($this->Test->User->save())
{
echo 'success';
}
else{
echo 'faliure';
}